# White space below image inside inline-block div

Tags: html, css, image

There is whitespace below image in every browser I use. 
It has `display: block;` and `vertical-align: top;` properties, but still, there is that whitespace. Image is inside of `inline-block` element, could it be because of it?
Code is below, thank you for every advice!
[image: image whitespace]

HTML:

```
      <div class="zazitek-tab">
        <div class="zazitek-img">
          <img src="style/car-order.png">
        </div>
        <div class="zazitek-text">
          <div class="zazitek-obsah">
            <h2>Jízda ve Ferrari</h2>
            <p class="description">Vozy se vzpínajícím se hřebcem patří mezi legendy mezi automobily...</p>
            <span class="price">1 500 Kč</span>
            <span class="info-but"><a href="#">Více informací</a></span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

CSS:

```
.zazitek-tab {width: 80%; display: block; margin: 0 auto; margin-top: 3%; padding: 0;
-webkit-box-shadow: 5px 6px 15px -4px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
-moz-box-shadow: 5px 6px 15px -4px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
box-shadow: 5px 6px 15px -4px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
transition: 0.3s;}

.zazitek-tab:hover {
-webkit-box-shadow: -5px -4px 15px -4px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
-moz-box-shadow: -5px -4px 15px -4px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
box-shadow: -5px -4px 15px -4px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
}

.zazitek-img {width: 30%; padding: 0 !important; margin: 0; display: inline-block; line-height: 0;}
.zazitek-img img {width: 100% !important; display: block !important; vertical-align: top; height: auto; margin: 0 !important; padding: 0;}
.zazitek-text {width: 65%; padding: 0 !important; margin: 0; display: inline-block; vertical-align: top;}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Image inside div has extra space below the image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5804256/image-inside-div-has-extra-space-below-the-image)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`vertical-align` should be used in the element where you've used `inline-block`

try this, it will fix your problem

Comment: no problem, don't forget to accept the answer though